BadgeFormatter Plugin Not Matching Conditions in Joget
I'm currently developing a custom data list formatter plugin for Joget (DX8) called BadgeFormatter. The plugin is designed to display values with different types of Bootstrap badges based on specified conditions. However, I'm encountering an issue where the condition values are not being matched correctly, leading to incorrect badge types being applied.
Here’s the main code for the BadgeFormatter class:
package org.joget.tutorial;

import java.util.Map;
import org.joget.apps.app.service.AppUtil;
import org.joget.apps.datalist.model.DataList;
import org.joget.apps.datalist.model.DataListColumn;
import org.joget.apps.datalist.model.DataListColumnFormatDefault;
import org.joget.commons.util.LogUtil;

public class BadgeFormatter extends DataListColumnFormatDefault {

    @Override
    public String format(DataList dataList, DataListColumn column, Object row, Object value) {
        String result = (value != null) ? value.toString() : "";

        if (!result.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                String badgeType = getPropertyString("badgeType");
                if (badgeType == null || badgeType.isEmpty()) {
                    badgeType = "primary";
                }

                Object[] conditionsArray = (Object[]) getProperty("conditions");

                LogUtil.info(getClassName(), "Processing value: " + result);
                if (conditionsArray != null) {
                    LogUtil.info(getClassName(), "Conditions array length: " + conditionsArray.length);
                } else {
                    LogUtil.info(getClassName(), "Conditions array is null");
                }

                if (conditionsArray != null && conditionsArray.length > 0) {
                    for (Object conditionObj : conditionsArray) {
                        if (conditionObj instanceof Map) {
                            Map<String, String> condition = (Map<String, String>) conditionObj;

                            LogUtil.info(getClassName(), "Condition map: " + condition.toString());

                            String conditionValue = condition.get("value");
                            String conditionBadge = condition.get("badge");

                            LogUtil.info(getClassName(), "Checking condition: Value=" + conditionValue + ", Badge=" + conditionBadge);

                            if (conditionValue != null && conditionBadge != null) {
                                if (conditionValue.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(result.trim())) {
                                    badgeType = conditionBadge.toLowerCase();
                                    LogUtil.info(getClassName(), "Match found! Applying badge: " + badgeType);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                LogUtil.info(getClassName(), "Final badge type applied: " + badgeType);
                result = "<span class=\"badge badge-" + badgeType + "\" style=\"font-size: 14px;\">" + result + "</span>";

            } catch (Exception e) {
                LogUtil.error(getClassName(), e, "Error in BadgeFormatter plugin");
                result = "<span class=\"badge badge-primary\" style=\"font-size: 14px;\">" + result + "</span>";
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}


The configuration for the plugin is defined in a JSON file that specifies the conditions:
[
    {
        "title": "Badge Formatter Configuration",
        "properties": [
            {
                "name": "badgeType",
                "label": "Default Badge Type",
                "type": "selectbox",
                "options": [
                    {"value": "primary", "label": "Primary"},
                    {"value": "secondary", "label": "Secondary"},
                    {"value": "success", "label": "Success"},
                    {"value": "danger", "label": "Danger"},
                    {"value": "warning", "label": "Warning"},
                    {"value": "info", "label": "Info"},
                    {"value": "light", "label": "Light"},
                    {"value": "dark", "label": "Dark"}
                ],
                "required": true
            },
            {
                "name": "conditions",
                "label": "Badge Conditions",
                "type": "grid",
                "columns": [
                    {"name": "value", "label": "Value", "type": "textfield"},
                    {
                        "name": "badge",
                        "label": "Badge Type",
                        "type": "selectbox",
                        "options": [
                            {"value": "primary", "label": "Primary"},
                            {"value": "secondary", "label": "Secondary"},
                            {"value": "success", "label": "Success"},
                            {"value": "danger", "label": "Danger"},
                            {"value": "warning", "label": "Warning"},
                            {"value": "info", "label": "Info"},
                            {"value": "light", "label": "Light"},
                            {"value": "dark", "label": "Dark"}
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]


Here’s the relevant output from the logs when processing the value "Approved":
INFO  07 Oct 2024 17:35:56 org.joget.tutorial.BadgeFormatter - Processing value: Approved
INFO  07 Oct 2024 17:35:56 org.joget.tutorial.BadgeFormatter - Conditions array length: 1
INFO  07 Oct 2024 17:35:56 org.joget.tutorial.BadgeFormatter - Condition map: {undefined=approved}
INFO  07 Oct 2024 17:35:56 org.joget.tutorial.BadgeFormatter - Checking condition: Value=null, Badge=null
INFO  07 Oct 2024 17:35:56 org.joget.tutorial.BadgeFormatter - Final badge type applied: info


My expectation was that when the data passed to the formatter matches specific values defined in the conditions, the corresponding badge type would be applied correctly.
However, while debugging, I found that the conditions array was being logged correctly, but the values for the conditions were returning as null in the logs. Instead of applying the expected badge type, the plugin defaulted to the "info" badge, indicating that it failed to match any conditions.
I also noticed that the condition map logged shows undefined=approved, which suggests that the keys in the condition might not be defined correctly. I'm seeking insights on why the conditions are not being recognized and how to ensure that the correct badge types are applied based on the values passed to the formatter.
